# Sails.js: Missing fields with req.files on a slow internet connection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload like this:

```
  Upload.upload({
    url: $window.location.origin + "/somepath",
    data: {
      transformTo: Upload.json($scope.corners.nodes),
      transformFrom: Upload.json(anotherObject),
      file: $scope.files //--> the files object of a single file populated by the ng-file-upload directive
    },
    objectKey: '.k'
  }).progress(function (e) {
  ...
```

Then, in the sailsjs controller:

```
 somepath: function (req, res) {
     req.file('file').upload({dirname: 'assets/images/uploads/'}, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
     if (err) return res.send(500, err);
     var transformFrom = req.param('transformFrom');
     var transformTo = req.param('transformTo');
     sails.log.info(transformFrom)
     sails.log.info(transformTo);
     ...
```

If I'm in localhost, it works ok. Uploads the file and prints the two variables.

BUT, if I'm in production or in localhost but simulating a slow internet connection (throttling) with Chrome, then I got the transformFrom and transformTo fields as "undefined"

Any clue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about your application files, meaning where you declare your controllers and other stuff, are they being loaded in head or body?

Comment: Are you propossing the issue is not in the backend but rather in the front-end? I've checked the network tab and it looks like the http request is ok both times.

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundaryqaW8MzutOxS1G8Ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transformTo"

[{"x":"85","y":"228"},{"x":"2367","y":"250"},{"x":"2423","y":"1810"},{"x":"70","y":"1705"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryqaW8MzutOxS1G8Ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transformFrom"

[{"x":"0","y":"0"},{"x":"2282","y":"0"},{"x":"2282","y":"1477"},{"x":"0","y":"1477"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryqaW8MzutOxS1G8Ee
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="zczwgdrs0lsjxzvhbqcd.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryqaW8MzutOxS1G8Ee--
Name
lookup.html

Comment: That's the request payload, both with and without networking throttling.

Comment: Hm, can you start Sails with `DEBUG=skipper sails lift` and see if Skipper (the body parser module) has any more information for you?